# breeze - sending header to server doesnt work

Tags: c#, angularjs, breeze

I am trying to send a custom header to the server. But I dont see it in the Request Headers on the server. 
I tried using the following:

```
var ajaxImpl = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance("ajax");
 ajaxImpl.defaultSettings = {
       headers: { 
           // any CORS or other headers that you want to specify.
           "X-Test-Header": "foo2" 
       },
};
```

as well as:

```
 var ajaxImpl = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance("ajax");
 ajaxImpl.defaultSettings = {
       beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
              // examine the jqXHR or settings and customize the headers accordingly.
              jqXHR.setRequestHeader("X-Test-Before-Send-Header", "foo2");
       }
 };
```

And I tried using "ajax"as well as "dataService" as the AdapterInstance.
I have no idea why this should not work...

Comment: Are you using the [Breeze Angular Service](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/breeze-angular.html) to configure Breeze to work with AngularJS?

Comment: @SteveSchmitt  We are using Breeze.WebApi2